# Incomplete file download when using Windows (Java)

Tags: java

I can't realize why my file download function perfectly works on Linux, but on Windows it only downloads 1-2 KB of file and finishes. What am I doing wrong? I've already tried approx. 3 examples from Stack Overflow, but no result. Big thanks, you'll save my mind!

```
public static void get(String URL, String filename) throws IOException, ArithmeticException {
    URL connection = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.connect();
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    byte buffer[] = new byte[55000];
    int c = in.read(buffer);
    while (c > 0) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, c);
        c = in.read(buffer);
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: What about Apache's Http-components ?

Comment: So the code above works on linux, but not on windows? 
The first thing you need to check is that you're using the same JVM on both platforms, so that you can exclude the possibility of that being the cause of your problems.

Comment: I'm crazy a bit on making the most small application. It is now 28,1 KB in size. Sorry, I can't use any Apache libraries due to that.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try to update JVMs. But what change could be in them, that 1.7.0_51 works well and older doesn't? Oh, I'll need to add Java version checking then :P

Comment: One of my users reported that he is using the same JVM as I. It seems like JVM version not a troublemaker. I'll try to run application on Windows under VirtualBox using different versions soon.

Comment: Can it affect that I run this function in another thread using run()?

Comment: Possibly. The underlying OS threads are different, after all. If I were you I'd check my thread handling to see that everything's ok there. Speculation: Maybe you don't keep a reference to the thread, and it happens to get killed faster on windows than on linux. Hence the linux thread can finish the download, but the windows thread can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only blame my stupidness :) I used `File.separator` in URL instead of normal `"/"`. As Linux has the same slash as URL's, everything is OK, but not on Windows. Like Linux slashes, and you? Thanks for contributing!